# SQL query to Access format

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a SQL query which works for my solution in SQL. Given the location and software I currently have, i'm unable to use my Oracle software. I'm currently travelling and trying to do some extra work.

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT tt.supplierId, tt.Price
FROM products tt
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SupplierID, MAX(price) AS [prices]
FROM products
GROUP BY SupplierID ) groupedtt 
ON tt.SupplierID = groupedtt.SupplierID
AND tt.price = groupedtt.price
```

When trying to run this in Access, I get a number of errors, from 'enter parameter value', to missing expressions.  I haven't used Access for a very long time and am 'rusty' on the syntax. I've tried a variety of different ways to make it work in Access, with no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` between the two conditions in the `ON` clause.

```sql
ON tt.SupplierID = groupedtt.SupplierID
AND tt.price = groupedtt.price
```

Access sometimes objects when you try to reuse a field name as the alias for a field expression.

If this segment causes an error ...

```sql
SELECT SupplierID, MAX(price) AS price
```

... use one of these two instead ...

```sql
SELECT SupplierID, MAX(price) AS Maxprice
SELECT SupplierID, MAX(price) AS [price]
```

If Access continues to request a parameter value, please indicate what it interprets as the name of the parameter.  You can find that out by running the query from the Access query designer --- the input parameter dialog includes the parameter name.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean to have the AND on my query. I'm getting Enter parameter value for groupedtt.price

Comment: Max(price) AS [prices]

Comment: With `MAX(price) AS [prices]` in the subquery, you'll need to change the `ON` clause to match: `AND tt.price = groupedtt.prices`  Otherwise, Access will look for `price` in `groupedtt`, not find it, and therefore assume it must be a parameter.